# Change the seed of RAND() function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I accessed my table of database by a PHP script and I get continuous repeat results sometimes.

*I ran this query:*

```
$query ="SELECT Question,Answer1,Answer2 FROM MyTable ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) LIMIT 1";
```

Before of this query, I tried just with  `ORDER BY RAND()`, but it gave me a lot of continuous repeat results, that's why I decided to use `ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))`.
But this last one still give me continuous repeat results( but less).

Im going to write a example to explain what I mean when I said *"continuous repeat results"* :

Image that I have 100 rows in my table: ROW1,ROW2,ROW3,ROw4,ROW5...
well, when I call my script PHP 5 times continuosly I get 5 results:
           -*ROW2,ROW20,ROW20,ROW50,ROW66*

I don't want same row continuously two times.
I would like it for example:  -*ROW2,ROW20,ROW50,ROW66,ROW20*

I just want to fix it some easy way.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way
>   to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between
>   platforms for the same MySQL version.

If you want 5 results, why not change the limit to 5 ? This will ensure that there are no duplicates

The other option is read all of the data out, and then use shuffle in php ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Or select the max and use a random number generated from PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

This is *not doable by just redefining the query.* You need to change the logic of your PHP script.

If you want that the PHP script (and the query) returns exactly ONE row per execution, and you need a guarantee that **repeated executions** of the PHP scrips yield different rows, then **you need to store the previous result somewhere,** and use the previous result in the `WHERE` condition of the query.

So your PHP script becomes something like (pseudocode):

```
$previousId = ...; // Load the ID of the row fetched by the previous execution

$query = "SELECT Question,Answer1,Answer2 
      FROM MyTable 
      WHERE id <> ?
      ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) 
      LIMIT 1";

// Execute $query, using the $previousId bound parameter value

$newId = ...; // get the ID of the fetched row.

// Save $newId for the next execution.
```

You may use all kinds of storages for saving/loading the ID of the fetched rows. The easiest is probably to use a special table with a single row in the same database for this purpose.

---

Note that you may *still* get repeated sequential rows if you call your PHP script many times *in parallel*. Not sure if it matters in your case.
If it does, you may use *locks* or *database transactions* to fix this as well.